# Facebook at work graph API, error getting the message?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebookatwork

I need help with facebook graph API, and facebook at work.

I'm making website that will pull posts from facebook at work group, and there will be like and comment button on each post to direct like or comment from site.

So the problem I'm facing is that I get this error when I try to post like to some post.

```
{
 "error": {
 "message": "(#100) Error getting the message",
 "type": "OAuthException",
 "code": 100,
 "fbtrace_id": "A32JqNTzgaG"
 }
}
```

I tried the same thing on normal facebook page and it work's, but on facebook at work page it doesn't.

Maybe I'm missing something.

I will paste the code here, it's not clean, but it should work, the get request works fine.

If anyone can help it would be great. Thanks. :)

```
(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
    var accessToken, uid, impersonateToken;
    var pageAccessToken = '{facebook_at_work_acces_token}';

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
    $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js', function(){
        FB.init({
            appId: '{app_ID}',
            version: 'v2.7'
        });

        $( 'button.search' ).click(function() {
            FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
                    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
                        console.log('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
                    });
                } else {
                    console.log('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
                }
            }, {
                scope: 'publish_actions, email, user_likes',
                return_scopes: true
            });
        });

        FB.api(
            '/{logged_in_user_id}',
            'GET',
            {
                access_token : pageAccessToken,
                "fields":"impersonate_token"
            },
            function(response) {
                impersonateToken = response;
                console.log(impersonateToken);
            }
        );

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            if (response.status === 'connected') {
                console.log(response);

                uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                console.log(response);
            } else {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });

        $( '.like-wrap .like' ).click(function() {
            FB.api(
                "/{post_ID}/likes",
                "POST",
                {
                    access_token : pageAccessToken
                },
                function (response) {
                    if (response && !response.error) {
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                    console.log(response);
                }
            );
        });


        FB.api(
            '/{facebook_at_work_group_id}?fields=name,picture,cover,feed{likes,comments,message,story}',
            'GET',
            {
                access_token : pageAccessToken
            },
            function(response) {
                var icon_image = response.picture.data.url;
                var name = response.name;
                console.log(response);
                $('.facebook').each(function(i, val){
                    var message = response.feed.data[i].message;
                    $(this).prepend(
                        '<header class="entry-head">' +
                            '<img class="facebook-icon" src="'+icon_image+'">' +
                            '<h5>'+name+'</h5>' +
                            '<time>'+name+'</time>' +
                            '<p>'+message+'</p>' +
                        '</header>'
                    );
                });
            }
        );

    });
});
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Graphapi version 2.4 
 also make sure  you set the right privilege for your page access token